# Create virtual network

Tags: networking

Let's say i have a list of 5 IPs (myself included) and when i host a game on LAN(starcraft, aoe, warcraft..) i want the others 4 to see it on LAN.
Any tips of how to accomplish it?
I am looking forward to your replays.
Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

LAN play is for users on the LAN. If they're on the LAN, they should see your game. If they're not, there's no way to play with them on LAN mode unless you use something like [Hamachi](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hamachi).

Comment: Why the downvote? +1. This exactly what the OP is looking for; Hamachi is a simple VPN app.

Answer (score 1):

Setting up a VPN on windows requires one of the players to change router settings and be set up to receive incoming VPN connections. While not impossible, it's a rather more arduous process than using 3rd-party VPN applications.

These include Hamachi ([ceejayoz's answer](https://superuser.com/questions/88674/create-virtual-network/88675#88675) and my first choice), [Tunngle](http://www.tunngle.net/), and [Garena](http://www.garena.com).

There's a tutorial on using these applications to play Left-4-Dead-2 [here](http://versatile1.wordpress.com/2009/12/01/how-to-play-left-4-dead-2-lan-online-using-tunngle/).